# How to do a popup

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently working on an vscode extension. I'm trying to understand how I can create a "popup"/"tooltip" like this

[image: one].

I would like to know methods that I'm expected to use or an github link for an extension that is doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider` function ([Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features)) to do this.

I wrote a little demo extension that you can see here: https://github.com/ShPelles/vscode-hover-demo.

[image]

Comment: i don't understand, i'm working on javascript, i've tried some different code with **registerHoverProvider** and it still not working. If you have discord, could you add me please ? Pilot2_#7896

`const disposable = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider(['markdown', 'plaintext'], {
            provideHover(document, position, token) {
                console.log("debug")

                return {
                    contents: [`debug`],
                    range
                };
            }
        });    
        context.subscriptions.push(disposable)`

Comment: If you work on javascript, you should write something like:
`const disposable = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider(['javascript'], {provideHover(document, position, token) { console.log("debug"); return {contents: ['debug']} }});` And in your package.json you need to add this: `"activationEvents": ["onLanguage:javascript"],`

Comment: It still not logging anything and displaying anything.

Comment: Did the extension activated?  Did the provider called when you are hovering?try to add `console.log` or `debbuger;` in the `activate` function and in the provider.

Comment: I made a mistake, it's good now, but how can i display this popup when the text is selected ?

Comment: (selected not when hovered)